# Swift access to C Struct

Tags: c, swift, cocoa

I am developing a OS X Swift app for parsing cvs files. It runs successfully in Objective-C. Then I changed to Swift and for performance improvements I developed the parse/import engine in C. It is 5 times faster as in Swift or Objective-C - nice. But I have trouble to exchange the data between C and Swift - especially with Struct:

**BridgingHeader:**

```
#include "ToolBoxC.h"
```

**ToolBoxC.h:**

```
void loadFile(const char *fileName, const char *delimiters, const char *xRegex, int xRegexColumn, int xColumn, int yColumn, int xRow, int yRowShift, bool collectStrings);

typedef struct {

                    char **headerArray;
                    int numberHeaderRows;
                    char **dateArray;
                    int numberDateRows;
                    int **valueArray;
                    char ***stringArray;
                    int numberValueRows;
                    int numberValueColums;
        } FileStruct;

typedef struct {

                    FileStruct fileContent[10000];
} FilesStruct;

struct FilesStruct filesContent;
```

**ToolBoxC.c:**

```
struct FileStruct {

    char **headerArray;
    int numberHeaderRows;
    char **dateArray;
    int numberDateRows;
    int **valueArray;
    char ***stringArray;
    int numberValueRows;
    int numberValueColums;
};

struct FilesStruct {

    struct FileStruct fileContent[10000];
};

void loadFile(const char *fileName, const char *delimiters, const char *xRegex, int xRegexColumn, int xColumn, int yColumn, int xRow, int yRowShift, bool collectStrings) {

// some stuff

    struct FileStruct fileContent;

    fileContent.headerArray = headerArray;
    fileContent.numberHeaderRows = numberHeaderRows;
    fileContent.dateArray = dateArray;
    fileContent.numberDateRows = numberDateRows;
    fileContent.valueArray = valueArray;
    fileContent.stringArray = stringArray;
    fileContent.numberValueRows = numberValueRows;
    fileContent.numberValueColums = numberValueColumns;

    filesContent.fileContent[numberFiles] = fileContent;

return;
}
```

All the parsed data are stored in `struct FilesStruct filesContent`. The parsing is started by calling the function loadFile() with parameters from Swift. That works fine. Also the parsing is OK. But how can I access to the data in `struct FilesStruct filesContent` from Swift?

Thanks, Matthias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**ToolBoxC.h**

```
#include <stdbool.h>

struct FileStruct {
    char **headerArray;
    int numberHeaderRows;
    char **dateArray;
    int numberDateRows;
    int **valueArray;
    char ***stringArray;
    int numberValueRows;
    int numberValueColums;
};

extern struct FileStruct **loadedFiles;

void loadFile(const char *fileName, const char *delimiters, const char *xRegex, int xRegexColumn, int xColumn, int yColumn, int xRow, int yRowShift, bool collectStrings);
```

**ToolBoxC.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ToolBoxC.h"

#define MaxFiles 10000

struct FileStruct **loadedFiles;

void loadFile(const char *fileName, const char *delimiters, const char *xRegex, int xRegexColumn, int xColumn, int yColumn, int xRow, int yRowShift, bool collectStrings) {

    static int nextIndex = 0;

    if (loadedFiles == 0)
        loadedFiles = malloc(MaxFiles * sizeof(*loadedFiles));

    struct FileStruct *file = malloc(sizeof(struct FileStruct));
    file->numberDateRows = xRow;

    loadedFiles[nextIndex++] = file;
}
```

**Swift Test Method**

```
func loadFilesTest() -> Void {
    for var i:Int32 = 0; i < 10; ++i {
        loadFile("", "", "", 0, 0, 0, i, 0, true)
    }
    for var j = 0; j < 10; ++j {
        let pointer = UnsafePointer<FileStruct>(loadedFiles[j])
        print("Number of date rows = \(pointer.memory.numberDateRows)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, Robert. I don't understand it completely - but it works fine.

Comment: You are very welcome, @user2156649. Please feel free to ask any question about it; I will do my best to answer.

Comment: There is one more problem....with memory management. The C function loadfile() is called by Swift multi-threaded. So can many files processed concurrently. In the Swift part I use NSOperationQueue. My question is: Is malloc thread safe? Often it works w/o problems, but sometimes I get "malloc: *** error for object: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug".